# How to import complete folder into SVN repository

Tags: svn

When I try to import my project using the command:

`svn import  /root/dummyProject file:///home/svn/dummyProjet/ -m "Intial project"`,

It creates the project only with the project contents. It doesn't create a project folder name which I wanted to maintain.

For example: when I try to checkout the project, only the contents of the folder appear and not the folder containing the project contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how Subversion is supposed to work. See the [Documentation for Import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import).

So if your local directory structure is the following, and you want to import `sub_dir1` into `file:///home/svn/dummyProject`:

```
/root/dummyProject
  /sub_dir1
    file1.ext
    file2.ext
  /sub_dir2
```

You should do the command like that:

```
svn import /root/dummyProject/sub_dir1 file:///home/svn/dummyProject/sub_dir1 -m "Initial project"
```

As a result, the directory `sub_dir1` will be created in the repository, and filled with the content of your local directory.